# Trying to understand Precedence Rule 4 in Scala In Depth Book

Tags: scala, operator-precedence

I am trying to understand the 4th rule on Precedence on Bindings on page 93 in Joshua Suareth's book Scala in depth.

According to this rule:

> definitions made available by a package clause not in the source file where the definition occurs have lowest precedence.

It is this rule that I intend to test.

So off I went and tried to follow Josh's train of thought on Page 94. He creates a source file called externalbindings.scala and I did the same, with some changes to it as below

```
package com.att.scala

class extbindings {
  def showX(x: Int): Int = {
    x
  }

  object x1 {
    override def toString = "Externally bound obj object in com.att.scala"
  }
}
```

Next he asks us to create another file that will allow us to test the above rule. I created a file called precedence.scala:

```
package com.att.scala

class PrecedenceTest { //Josh has an object here instead of a class

  def testPrecedence(): Unit = { //Josh has main method instead of this
    testSamePackage()
    //testWildCardImport()
    //testExplicitImport()
    //testInlineDefinition()
  }

  println("First statement of Constructor")
  testPrecedence
  println("Last statement of Constructor")

  def testSamePackage() {
    val ext1 = new extbindings()
    val x = ext1.showX(100)
    println("x is "+x)
    println(obj1) // Eclipse complains here
  }
}
```

Now, Josh is able to print out the value of the object in his example by simply doing the `<package-name>.<object-name>.testSamePackage` method on the REPL.
His output is:

> Externally bound x object in package test

In my versions, the files are in Eclipse and I have my embedded Scala interpreter.

Eclipse complains right here: `println(obj)`, it says: `not found value obj1`

Am I doing something obviously wrong in setting up the test files?
I would like to be able to test the rule I mentioned above and get the output:

> Externally bound obj object in package com.att.scala

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't read the book, thus I'm not really sure if your code shows what the book wants to tell you.

Nevertheless, the error message is correct. `obj1` is not found because it doesn't exist. In your code it is called `x1`. Because it is a member of `extbindings` you have to access it as a member of this class:

```
println(ext1.x1)
```

If `x1` is defined outside of class `extbinding`, in scope of package `com.att.scala`, you can access it directly:

```
println(x1)
```

If it is defined in another package you have to put the package name before:

```
println(com.att.scala2.x1)
```

To simplify some things you can import `x1`:

```
import ext1.x1
println(x1)
```

Finally a tip to improve your code: name types in `UpperCamelCase`: `extbindings` -> `Extbindings`, `x1` -> `X1`

Comment: I am glad you pointed that out.The mistake I made was to make object obj1 a member of the class extbindings. All your explanations are clear and informative.

Comment: I will implement the improvements you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

If you replace a singleton object with a class, you will need to create an instance of that class.